# Proof of a Ramanujan Statement

Tags: reference-request

I recently came across the approximation $$\ln n! \approx n\ln n - n + \frac{1}{6}\ln(n(1+4n(1+2n)))+\frac{1}{2}\ln \pi$$
Supposedly this was written in Ramanujan's last notebook, but I can't seem to find it anywhere else, nevermind a proof for it. Does anyone know if it was ever proven, and if so where such a proof is?

Comment: Sorry to say this, but it seems like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152342/ramanujans-approximation-to-factorial) has already been asked by someone else on Math SE.

Comment: Thanks for the link, not sure why I didn't come across that earlier.