# What is the best estimation of the factorial function?

Tags: factorial

I have to calculate factorials of an arbitrarily large integers mod another arbitrarily large integer. i have considered Stirling's Approximation and Ramanujan’s factorial approximation. is it possible to get better estimates?

Comment: If you are using modular arithmetic, analytic estimates might not be the most useful thing for you, depending on what exactly your problem is. Instead things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem might help.

Comment: There's the gamma function but I don't think it will help you much in contexts of modular arithmetic...

Comment: lets say, for the time being i just need to estimate the factorial. what will the nearest approximation be?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676952/is-ramanujans-approximation-for-the-factorial-optimal-or-can-it-be-tweaked-a/677163#677163. For $n=20$, what I wrote gives $2432902008176665737$ to be compared to the exact $2432902008176640000$

Comment: Yes that's exactly what got me started on this path... that's a great answer.

Comment: I don't know if this could be of interest since the coefficients start to be huge. Using the same kind of expression with degree $2$ in numerator and degree $3$ in denominator, for $n=20$, I get $2432902008176639896$. If you want, I could post the numbers in an answer.

Comment: that seems like a better approximation, please do.

Comment: if i am not wrong totally, it is my understanding that as the factorial grows bigger and bigger, there are a certain number of trailing zeroes, if the percentage error can somehow be reduced to magnitude, wont we be able to just ignore the error?

Comment: Also how did you come up with these numbers? could you please explain?

Comment: Comparing to high order expansion of Stirling formula.

Comment: I wish i knew half of the math you know!!!

Comment: Be sure I don't know much ! I am just old. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86113/discussion-between-malik-hamza-murtaza-and-claude-leibovici).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing
$$n!\approx\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\root\LARGE{6}\of{8n^3+4n^2+n+\frac 1 {30}\color{red}{-}x(n)}$$ with 
$$x(n)=\frac{a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2}{b_0+b_1n+b_2n^2+b_3n^3}$$ the coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_0 & 12521740840824081\\
 a_1 & 132077016740516320 \\
 a_2 & 261892615461486240 \\
 b_0 &3339455095907419720 \\
 b_1 & 7902477164268212400 \\
 b_2 & 5812898776788230400
\end{array}
\right)$$
A few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 10 & 3628800 & 3628800 \\
 15 & 1307674368000 & 1307674368000 \\
 20 & 2432902008176639896 & 2432902008176640000 \\
 25 & 15511210043330985910414618 & 15511210043330985984000000 \\
 30 & 265252859812191058429178640362769 & 265252859812191058636308480000000 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Using ratios of polyomials (as done in this answer and the previous one) leads to incredibly huge coefficients. Thinking more about it, I thought that is would be better to just write
$$x(n)=\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{a_k}{n^k}$$ and, when required, transform this expansion to the desired $[p,p+1]$ Padé approximant. The coefficients so obtained are listed below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & a_k \\
 1 & \frac{11}{240} \\
 2 & -\frac{79}{3360} \\
 3 & -\frac{3539}{201600} \\
 4 & \frac{9511}{403200} \\
 5 & \frac{10051}{716800} \\
 6 & -\frac{233934691}{6386688000} \\
 7 & -\frac{3595113569}{178827264000} \\
 8 & \frac{403527851669}{4649508864000} \\
 9 & \frac{25622861661869}{557941063680000} \\
 10 & -\frac{30016604936501}{101443829760000} \\
 11 & -\frac{685661227463561}{4463528509440000} \\
 12 & \frac{109896661164737049961}{79673983893504000000}
\end{array}
\right)$$ For $n=25$, this would lead to $\color{blue}{1551121004333098598400000}5$.

For $n=30$ , this would lead to $\color{blue}{26525285981219105863630848}5359781$.

This seems to be significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

Stirlings approximation is good ... *especially* if in the expression for $\ln(n!)$ you include the series in odd powers of 1/n. Are you aware of that series - Stirlings aporoximation is all-too-often given without it. The coefficients of it are not too compliated - Bernoulli numbers multiplied by simple factors. Ah yes! maybe it is troublesome for very large n then because of that - the way the Bernoulli numbers 'turn round'.

This *might* answer your question though.